# Excel VBA Shape in Header

Tags: excel, vba, image, header

I'm currently working on a worksheet where I want to print a certain shape/picture on the header of the print page. Right now, I have saved the picture on my pc and call it from there. However, the workbook is going to be spread, and I just don't want everybody to download the picture. I have de picture currently in the same worksheet as what needs to be printed however it would be a dream if the picture could also be in a different worksheet within the workbook. The name of the picture = Logo. The code I use right now is when the picture is downloaded locally on the pc.

```
Dim PathLogo As String
PathLogo = Sheets("HOME").Range("BI78").Value

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeaderPicture
        .Filename = PathLogo
        .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
        .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    End With


With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$A$2:$X$103"
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .HeaderMargin = 0
    .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .CenterVertically = True
    .RightHeader = "&G"
    .CenterHeader = "&B&16&U&K595959" & Worksheets("HOME").Range("AJ71").Value
    .RightFooter = "&D" & " " & "&T"
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:X103").PrintOut
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Insert picture in header from picture located in workbook](https://superuser.com/questions/1053398/insert-picture-in-header-with-vba-from-picture-located-in-workbook)

Comment: @T.M. This could work indeed. However, isn't this very slow?

Comment: Did you try, is it actually too slow? - Had no time to test this idea: what about integrating an image in an archivating userform? @WouterGroeneweg